# Can a Sonoff Basic Switch be connected between a wall switch and a light?

Tags: electrical, wiring

Newbie here from India.

I was wondering if a [Sonoff Basic switch](https://sonoff.itead.cc/en/products/sonoff/sonoff-basic) can be connected as given in the diagram below:

[image]

The "Light Switch on the Wall" stays always in the 'On' position. And the Sonoff switch disrupts the flow of electricity.

Disclaimer: I am not an electrician. I will be getting this connected by a qualified electrician.

Edit: Changed the diagram to better reflect how a switch works

Comment: no, it cannot. switches don't switch L and N, just L. that means you cold only get power parasitically through the bulb, and only if the switch was on could you turn off the bulb with wifi.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was trying to say. The wall switch would always be on. Is this bad design?

Comment: i would remove the switch then. re-examine the sonoff wiring diagrams; there's two options that will work for your situations. the problem is your switch diagram, that's' not how switches are wired.

Comment: I have edited the diagram to better reflect how a switch works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason that wouldn't work unless the manufacturer advises against it. It's a possibility that frequent on/off cycling isn't good for it, but that's unlikely. It's somewhat likely that there will be a wifi reconnect lag, however, so take that into consideration.

Really, this is no different than a typical motion detector on a switch loop.

Comment: Thanks v.much for your answer. There's not much manufacturer documentation about going about wiring it, but there's no advise against wiring it this way. I was confused because there is also the alternative of connecting the Sonoff Basic switch in the wall IN PLACE OF the wall switch. I guess that would be alright too?

Comment: Sure. It's all just a loop. You could put 37 different types of switches in it if you like.